# Всплывающие окна поисковика на Node JS

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js

Сделал всплывающие окна поисковика, но работает с проблемами. А именно: по какой-то причине при отжатии клавиши код срабатывает дважды (возможно баг JQuery), и в целом он может бесконечно добавлять строки, а должен высвечивать только нужные результаты.

HTML+JS:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#search").keyup(function() {
    var name = $('#search').val();
    if (name === "") {
      $("#display").html("");
    } else {
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/handler",
        data: {
          search: name
        },
        success: function(response) {
          for (i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
            $("#display").append(`<li onclick="fill('${response[i].name}')"><a>${response[i].name}</a></li>`);
          }
        }
      });
    }
  });
});

function fill(Value) {
  $('#search').val(Value);
  $('#display').hide();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="search">
  <form class="example" method="POST">
    <input type="text" autocomplete="off" name="search" id="search" placeholder="Search..">
    <button type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
  </form>
  <div id="display">
  </div>
```

Код серверной части Node JS:

```
app.post("/handler", (req, res) => {
  item.find({
    name: {
      $regex: req.body.search,
      $options: 'i'
    }
  }).limit(5).then((name) => {
    res.send(name);
  });
});
```

Comment: Очищай блок результатов перед добавлением.

Comment: и проверь что приходит в респонсе.   возможно там ошибка